# Where are the instructions to open and view the VirtoCommerce store in Visual Studio?

Tags: virtocommerce

I see there are instructions to set up the webadmin part for VirtoCommerce which I was able to follow. How do you view the actual store? What is the vc-community-master.zip used for? Where are the instructions for using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Master branch is for 1.13 version currently. If you want to setup webadmin, use the webadmin branch. Instructions for setting up are here:

http://docs.virtocommerce.com/display/vc2devguide/Source+Code+Getting+Started.

Hope this helps! There are two sites, frontend and backend that need to be setup.

Comment: So vc-community-webadmin.zip is for the 2.0 admin? Where's the 2.0 frontend site? Is vc-community-webadmin.zip for both the frontend and backend 2.0?

Comment: Also that's the instructions I mentioned I followed.it doesn't include the front end part for the store itself.

Comment: Yes, webadmin is for both frontend and backend. To configure frontend open the STOREFRONT\VirtoCommerce.Website.sln and either launch it from visual studio or setup an IIS site pointing to "Website" folder. Make sure to specify connection string to web api inside connectionStrings.config. We will add instructions to the guide for frontend.